# How To Get Query Result and Count Of Result In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Want To Get Query Result and Count Of Row Result But I Can`t Get both of them.

Under The Post I Write My Query And I Cant Find Response Of Problem Another StackOverFlow s Posts

Please Help Me

My Query Is:

```
select count(*) from (
                                    select http.RequestTime, http.StatusCode as StatusCodeApiRequestDetail
                                , http.RequestHeaderContent, http.RequestBodyContent, http.ResponseBodyContent,
                                http.ElapsedMilliseconds as ElapsedMillisecondsApiRequestDetail,
                                http.Host,http.QueryString, http.Path,
                                null as RequestDateOutgoing,null as StatusCodeOutgoing,null as ReasonPhrase,null as Headers,null as Body,
                                null as ResponseContent,null as ElapsedMillisecondsOutgoing,
                                soaReq.RequestDate as RequestDateSoapApiRequest, soaReq.Body
                               as BodySoapApiRequest, soapRes.Response as ResponseSoapApiResponse,service.Name as ServiceName
                                from Logs_ApiRequestResponseDetails as http
                                             inner JOIN dbo.OutgoingSoapRequestLogs AS soaReq ON soaReq.CorrelationId = http.CorrelationId
                                                inner JOIN dbo.OutgoingSoapResponseLogs AS soapRes ON soapRes.CorrelationId = http.CorrelationId
                                                LEFT JOIN dbo.Logs_ApiMappings AS mapping ON http.ApiMappingId = mapping.Id
                                                LEFT JOIN dbo.Clients_ServiceItems AS service ON mapping.ServiceId = service.Id
                                                where http.CorrelationId !='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                                                --group by http.RequestTime

                                                Union all
                                                    select http.RequestTime, http.StatusCode as StatusCodeApiRequestDetail
                                , http.RequestHeaderContent, http.RequestBodyContent, http.ResponseBodyContent,
                                http.ElapsedMilliseconds as ElapsedMillisecondsApiRequestDetail,
                                --http.OsName, http.OsVersion, http.ClientIp, http.AppVersion,
                                http.Host,
                                http.QueryString, http.Path,
                                out.RequestDate as RequestDateOutgoing, out.StatusCode as StatusCodeOutgoing, out.ReasonPhrase, out.Headers,out.Body,
                                out.ResponseContent, out.ElapsedMilliseconds as ElapsedMillisecondsOutgoing,
                                null as RequestDateSoapApiRequest, null
                                as BodySoapApiRequest, null as ResponseSoapApiResponse,service.Name 
                                from Logs_ApiRequestResponseDetails as http
                                            inner JOIN dbo.Logs_OutgoingApiRequests AS out ON out.CorrelationId = http.CorrelationId
                                            LEFT JOIN dbo.Logs_ApiMappings AS mapping ON http.ApiMappingId = mapping.Id
                                                LEFT JOIN dbo.Clients_ServiceItems AS service ON mapping.ServiceId = service.Id
                                                where http.CorrelationId !='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') cte
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Use subquery. Something like: SELECT **, (select COUNT(*) from [your query]) as Counter from  [your query]

Comment: Please sort out the formatting mess, it's unreadable. Use a window function `SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () FROM ...`